# Javascript hide/show - more elegant way to do this?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, unobtrusive-javascript

I'm looking for a more elegant way to make a hide/show of divs using inline Javascript.

If you mouse over the orangish/yellow circle logos over the cars the tag should appear. When moused out they should disappear.

URL:

[http://174.120.239.48/~peakperf/](http://174.120.239.48/%7Epeakperf/)

```
<div class="second">
    <div id="speech2" style="display: none">
        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/speech2.png" width="334" height="50">
        </div>
    <a id="various2" href="#inline2,javascript:HideContent('speech1')" title="" onmouseover="HideContent('speech1'); return true;">
        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/clicker.png" width="62" height="50" onmouseover="document.getElementById('speech2').style.display = 'block'" onmouseout="document.getElementById('speech2').style.display = 'none'">
    </a>
</div>
```

Here's the pastebin of the code used:

http://pastebin.com/JsW6eJRZ

Comment: "using inline javascript" There's no elegant way to do _anything_ with inline javascript

Comment: I totally agree. The code was inherited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The more elegant solution is to utilize JQuery.
Once you include the library into a file, a div show is done using the following selector

```
$('#idOfDiv').show();
```

Or if there are no ids but rather classes

```
$('.ClassName').show();
```

Now instead of having onclick events in the html as you have right now, you just bind them in jquery in the ready() method like so:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $('#idOfDiv').bind('click', function()
   {
      //do work here in this anonymous callback function
   });
});
```

All of this can be done in a external js file so that will significantly clean up your html code 
and put all your javascript logic into one location.

**EDIT:**
Example applied to your situation

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
   $('#various1').mouseover(function()
   {
      $('#speech1').show();
   });

   $('#various1').mouseout(function()
   {
      $('#speech1').hide();
   });   
});
```

If you get crafty and utilize a for loop then you could just append the number to the end of the string that represents the selectors like so

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
   for(var i = 1; i < 7; i++)
   {
      $('#various' + i).mouseover(function()
      {
         $('#speech' + i).show();
      });

      $('#various' + i).mouseout(function()
      {
         $('#speech' + i).hide();
      });   
   }
});
```

The mouseout and mouseover functions are just the explicit version of using like so

```
$('selector').bind('mouseover', function()
{
});

$('selector').bind('mouseout', function()
{
});
```

Comment: @Raynos $(function() {}) shorthand for $(document).ready(function(){}) ?

Comment: Thank you Matthew! I have 6 of these bad boys. How would I go about doing it for 6 of them?

Comment: Worked like a charm Mr. Cox! You are awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into using jQuery for this? Also, why does the code need to be inlined?

I would recommend doing something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/4N9ym/2/

Note that I have things inverted here (you would probably want to animate in instead of animating out).